# Set of enum Spring data

Tags: spring, hibernate, enums, spring-data

I want to use in my spring application with spring data set of enums, which will be stored in db. Currently i tried it in that way:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ROLES")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class)
private Role role;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "PERMISSIONS")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Permission.class)
private Set<Permission> permissions;
```

but as you propably know it do not work. How can i use enums to be stored in db?

Best regards!

Comment: what is the problem exactly ? `@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class)` is not required. It is not a collection but a single enum.

Comment: the problem is with Set<Permission>, how to persist all of it ?

Comment: Are you looking for enumerating values within a database column? Here's a link which would help for that : http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `@CollectionTable` anotation with specified name and join column.

Answer (score 1):

May this will work for you.

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Permission.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "permissions", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
@Column(name = "permission", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Set<Permission> permission;
```